# Android-webview attachment issue with google mail

Tags: android, gmail, android-webview

I have a WebView in my application. I open google mail in this WebView.

Whenever I want to compose a new mail in this, I cannot attach any kind of files in the mail.

I have also used all WebView settings for the same.

Can anyone help me out in this issue?

**I should be able to attach files in the google mail, in WebView.**

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while attaching file from compose email in webview